Notification.requestPermission() on Angular 17 standalone + PWA + Firebase chrome/safari compatibility
I'm trying to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging but I'm having compatibility issues with Safari I don't know if it's due to the script or the test http-server I'm running it on.
Since @angular/fire is not yet standalone compatible I opted for direct interaction of Firebase interconnected with the pwa worker (@angular/pwa).
I created a firebase-setup.ts on which to include the dedicated code... the problem with Safari desktop (17.4.1) is that I get the notification acceptance request popup randomly... doing many page refreshes ... at you want by clicking Cmd+R Enter ... absurd.
FINAL SOLUTION ↓↓↓ ✅
firebase-setup.ts
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from 'firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);
let SWregistration: ServiceWorkerRegistration | undefined;

navigator.serviceWorker
  .getRegistration('./ngsw-worker.js')
  .then((registration) => {
    SWregistration = registration;
  });

// Ask for permission when the 'Enable notifications' button is clicked
export function askNotificationPermission() {
  // Function to actually ask the permissions
  function handlePermission(permission: any) {
    // Whatever the user answers, we make sure Chrome stores the information
    if (!Reflect.has(Notification, 'permission')) {
      // Notification.permission = permission;
    }

    // Set the button to shown or hidden, depending on what the user answers
    if (
      Notification.permission === 'denied' ||
      Notification.permission === 'default'
    ) {
    } else {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        getToken(messaging, {
          vapidKey: '...',
          serviceWorkerRegistration: SWregistration,
        })
          .then((currentToken) => {
            if (currentToken) {
              // To send to backend
              console.log(currentToken);
            } else {
              console.log(
                'No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.',
              );
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error token ', err);
          });
      }
    }
  }

  new Promise((resolve) => {
    Notification.requestPermission(resolve)?.then(resolve);
  }).then((permission) => handlePermission(permission));
}



main.ts
import '../firebase-setup'

app.component.ts
import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  swPush = inject(SwPush)

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscribePush()
    }

    subscribePush(): void {
      this.swPush.messages.subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          console.log(res, ' Message to show into notification')
        }
      )
    }
}

manifest.webmanifest
...

  "display": "standalone",
...

